# How to specify two elements in XSD with xs:choice, where both elements are also valid?

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="test">
<xs:choice  >
  <xs:element ref="mstns:element1" ></xs:element>
  <xs:element ref="mstns:element2" ></xs:element>
  <xs:sequence>        
    <xs:element ref="mstns:element1"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
    <xs:element ref="mstns:element2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ></xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```

Hi,

I am currently trying to write a XSD schema file, but I dont know how to specify
two elements where either both elements appear, or one of them. I tried above snippet, but it doesnt work, because it seems that no multiple element names are allowed.

What to do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your content model: is it `(A | B | AB)`, or is it `(A | B | AB | BA)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your content model: is it `(A | B | AB)`, or is it `(A | B | AB | BA)`?

In the first case you need to write it as

```
(A B? | B)
```

In the second case you need to write it as

```
(A B? | B A?)
```

where "|" represents choice and "?" represents optionality (and concatenation represents sequence).

Alternatively you could use xs:all.

This is needed to satisfy XSD's requirement for unambiguity without lookahead: when there is a choice, you must always be able to decide which branch to take without any lookahead in the input.

Comment: <xs:complexType name="t">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence >
      <xs:element ref="mstns:a"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
      <xs:element ref="mstns:b"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="mstns:b"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>      
    </xs:choice>    
  </xs:complexType> seems to work. Thank you.